# LibreOffice doc to html file conversion with embedded images

Tags: libreoffice

We've been using libreoffice's headless conversion to convert Word documents to HTML files. On version 4.0, it would create an HTML file and separate JPG files for any images embedded in the Word document and reference them via the img tag src attribute.

Now that we've upgraded to 4.2, the conversion only creates the HTML file, with all of the images embedded inline as base 64 encoded data-src attributes.

Is there a way to make the libreoffice conversion create the individually linked image files again? Here's the command we are using for the conversion:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to html:HTML file_to_convert.docx
```

Comment: If the issue depends on the LibreOffice version, you may try to use the [current stable version 4.4.5](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=win-x86&version=4.4.5&lang=de) or the ["fresh" 5.0.2 version](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?version=5.0.2) first.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [LibreOffice bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48887) which pointed me to this [commit](https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/commit/5dd1b3da57862a6577717544dde56482add89170?diff=unified) that shows that the functionality has changed and that it's caused problems for others as well. For now, there isn't a solution, but many folks on the bug report are requesting that the feature, to embed images, be optional. The issue ([according to a commenter of the bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48887#c25)) appears to be an issue in most recent version: 5.0.0rc2 and current master.